# How to change the directory highlight in the terminal buffer?

Tags: highlight, terminal-buffer, original-vim

I have a theme which is great apart from some minor things. I could already change the LineNr highlight and some others, but can't seem to change the directory highlight in the terminal buffer, which is barely readable. I had to set the termguicolors option to make the theme use the right colors. I might have to mention that I am using Konsole from KDE. I have already tried

```
hi Directory guifg=#686f9a ctermfg=141
hi Terminal guifg=#686f9a ctermfg=141
```

and they do nothing. Another solution would be to set a theme just for the terminal buffer. Not sure how this could be accomplished. I have tried

```
autocmd BufEnter * if getbufvar(bufnr('%'), '&buftype') == "terminal" | colorscheme default | endif
```

but it also doesn't work. This works for the help buffer, but then it also sets the global theme. I would only want to set it for that buffer. I guess per-buffer theming is not possible at all, is it?

[image]

Comment: Is this about Vim or Neovim?

Comment: It is a about Vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal in vim uses colors defined in the called terminal. For GUI vim (or when `termguicolors` is set you can define your own 16 colors to be used by built-in terminal:

For vim it is `:h g:terminal_ansi_colors` (taken from [vim-bronzage](https://github.com/habamax/vim-bronzage) colorscheme)

```
  let g:terminal_ansi_colors = ['#303030', '#d7875f', '#87af87', '#d7d787', '#87afd7', '#d7af5f', '#87d7d7', '#808080', '#4e4e4e', '#d75f5f', '#87af5f', '#afaf5f', '#5f8787', '#af875f', '#87afaf', '#e4e4e4']
```

Neovim uses set of `g:terminal_color_0..15`:

```
    let g:terminal_color_0 = '#303030'
    let g:terminal_color_1 = '#d7875f'
    let g:terminal_color_2 = '#87af87'
    let g:terminal_color_3 = '#d7d787'
    let g:terminal_color_4 = '#87afd7'
    let g:terminal_color_5 = '#d7af5f'
    let g:terminal_color_6 = '#87d7d7'
    let g:terminal_color_7 = '#808080'
    let g:terminal_color_8 = '#4e4e4e'
    let g:terminal_color_9 = '#d75f5f'
    let g:terminal_color_10 = '#87af5f'
    let g:terminal_color_11 = '#afaf5f'
    let g:terminal_color_12 = '#5f8787'
    let g:terminal_color_13 = '#af875f'
    let g:terminal_color_14 = '#87afaf'
    let g:terminal_color_15 = '#e4e4e4'
```

Make sure you have closed and opened a `:term` after defining those variables.

PS, what color to use for directory (blue, red, whatever) highlighting depends on your `ls` setup. One can set up it using `$LS_COLORS` env variable.

[image]

Comment: FYI, Neovim also supports syntax-highlighting for terminal window.

Comment: Thanks, the creator of the theme only set these for Neovim and I created an issue to notify him about it.